# Django distinct() not returning distinct values

Tags: django, django-queryset, distinct

I have a `Session` model like this:

```
class Session(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sessions")
    flavor = models.ForeignKey(Flavor, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sessions")
    ....
```

And I'm trying to run a query:

```
sessions = Session.objects.all().values('flavor__pk', 'user__pk').distinct()
```

But when I then print the sessions object I get this:

```
<QuerySet [{'user__pk': 14544, 'flavor__pk': 1}, {'user__pk': 14544, 'flavor__pk': 1}, {'user__pk': None, 'flavor__pk': 30}, {'user__pk': 193, 'flavor__pk': 30}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

Which, if you look closely, the first two entries are exactly the same `{'user__pk': 14544, 'flavor__pk': 1}`! Isn't this supposed to be distinct?

Comment: Do you have any default ordering specified? If you do, look at the first note [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: Note that `values('flavor_id', 'user_id').distinct()` will be equivalent and more efficient, since it doesn't have to JOIN the tables.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry In Django 2.1.7 (and probably earlier), `fk_field`, `fk_field_id` and `fk_field__pk` all result in an identical SQL query, so one less thing to worry about in newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

I think this code works:

```
Session.objects.all().values_list('flavor__pk', 'user__pk').distinct()
```

Comment: The SQL for `values()` and `values_list()` is identical (the difference being only in the Python representation); so this will not give different results from the OP's query.